# Компиляция и запуск программы из консоли

Tags: c

Хочу собрать программу из исходного файла на си. Для этого выполняю в консоле

```
bash$ gcc hello.c -o hello
```

результат

```
'bash$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,...
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: _"Файл на си"_ запустить нельзя в принципе. Можно написать программу на си, скомпилировать её и запустить полученный бинарник (`.exe` если это windows) на выполнение.

Answer (score 4):

Наверняка вы взяли это из какого-либо туториала. Обычно `bash$` добавлено просто в качестве примера приглашения командной строки. Сама же команда - `gcc hello.c -o hello`, только это и нужно писать.

Comment: Не, тоже самое(. Может нужно, что нибудь до этого прописать?

Comment: @Max Какая операционка и установлен ли компилятор C?

Comment: винда. ну я скачал прогу Dev-C++ и в самой ней все компилируется, а в консоле не получается. Туториал взял из вики

Comment: В комплекте с Dev-C++ устанавливается MinGW, необходимо найти папку, в которую он установлен и добавить папку `\bin` внутри неё в переменную `PATH`.

Comment: что то я не очень понял. папка bin уже есть и что значит добавить переменную PATH?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ee537574(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

команда `gcc hello.c -o hello` скомпилирует вам файл.
А для запуска его надо сделать исполнимым `chmod +x hello` и потом запускать `./hello`

Comment: chmod здесь лишний.

Comment: я понимаю, но судя по вопросу, товарищ совсем новичок и лучше перебдеть :)

Comment: Судя по комментариям, у товарища вообще Windows.